# Is something wrong with this method to take the screenshot in Selenium using C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot

When I try to call the below method from a test in order to capture a screenshot, it doesn't capture and return any screenshot. I am looking for the screenshot to be captured in bin/debug. I believe that the screenshots are not at all being captured. Can anyone help in identifying the issue with this if something is missing?

```
public void takeScreenshot()
{
    ITakesScreenshot screenshotHandler = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
    Screenshot screenshot = screenshotHandler.GetScreenshot();
    screenshot.SaveAsFile("ScreenShotAT" + DateTime.Now + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    screenshot.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Whats the `.` doing at the end of the third line? Have you checked your `Environment.CurrentDirectory`? Have you tried using a full path (`C:\Temp\test.png`)?

Comment: that .was just a typo while pasting the code, it doesn't exists in my program. Also tried with the full path and even that didn't worked out. let me check my Environment.CurrentDirectory now

Answer (score 2):

Path's format could be not supported. DateTime.Now return something like 9/1/2016 11:11:11 PM. It needs to be formatted like

```
dateTime.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ss_fff")
```

If you need unique file name use Unix timestamp.
It could be built by

```
(int) DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds
```

And method could look like.

```
public void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, String filename)
{
   Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
   screenshot.SaveAsFile(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void takeScreenShot()
        {
            string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, ddMMMyyyy HHmm");
            ITakesScreenshot screenshotHandler = DriverContext.Driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenshot = screenshotHandler.GetScreenshot();
            string dir = @"C:\Document\";
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(dir + currentDate + fileName + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

Where dir - directory where all your screenshots will be saved.

Answer (score -1):

During the test can you see the browser window? You might want to maximise the browser window before taking the screenshot.

a sample code from selenium site has following snippets which might help you:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
//The below method will save the screen shot in d drive with name "screenshot.png"
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\screenshot.png"));
```

[Taken from this site](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

See if this helps.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.